# Why does my script return 'NoneType'?

Tags: python, ogr, osgeo

I have this script and It return me some problem that I didn't find.

```
from osgeo import ogr
import os

class checkVectorMCV:

    def __init__(self, vector_path):

        self.vector_path = os.path.abspath(vector_path)
    def check_field_name(self):

        # Construindo a lista de campos do arquivo entregues

        daShapefile = self.vector_path
        print daShapefile, type(daShapefile)
        dataSource = ogr.Open(daShapefile)
        daLayer = dataSource.GetLayer(0)
        layerDefinition = daLayer.GetLayerDefn()

        #Construindo os campos dos arquivos entregues
        field = []

        for i in range(layerDefinition.GetFieldCount()):
            field.append(layerDefinition.GetFieldDefn(i).GetName())

        field = sorted(field)

        # Name of file with extension
        basename = os.path.basename(self.vector_path)

        # Name of file without extension
        name = os.path.splitext(basename)[0]

        #Comparação das listas de campos
        if (set(self.reference_field(name)) == set(field)) == False:
            return "Erro nos campos da camada: %s" % name;

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        ext = os.path.splitext(file)[-1].lower()
        #Print all files which have .shp extension
        if ext in extensions:
            arquivo = checkVectorMCV(file)         
            print arquivo.check_field_name()
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/infra/PycharmProjects/untitled/projeto_desenvolvimento_script/validacao_mapeamento_1.py", line 191, in <module>
        print arquivo.check_field_name()
      File "/home/infra/PycharmProjects/untitled/projeto_desenvolvimento_script/validacao_mapeamento_1.py", line 144, in check_field_name
        daLayer = dataSource.GetLayer(0)
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetLayer'
```

Comment: What is your `extensions` variable? Also, can you please edit your code to encapsulate the class construct to have at least a reproducible instance of your code to reproduce the error, i.e. `class checkVectorMCV(self):` as the first line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you you don't understand my answer in [Loading a Shapefile in standalone PyQGIS script](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/218073).

`osgeo.ogr` needs the complete path of a shapefile and
for this complete path, simply use `os.path.join(subdir, file)` and not `file` only (-> `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetLayer'`)

```
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
       if file.endswith(".shp"):
           print checkVectorMCV(os.path.join(subdir, file))
```

And in your class (without the test)

```
class checkVectorMCV(object):
   def __init__(self, vector_path):
        self.vector_path = vector_path # and not os.path.abspath(vector_path)
   def check_field_name(self):
        # Construindo a lista de campos do arquivo entregues
        daShapefile = self.vector_path
        #print daShapefile, type(daShapefile)
        dataSource = ogr.Open(daShapefile)
        daLayer = dataSource.GetLayer(0)
        layerDefinition = daLayer.GetLayerDefn()
        #Construindo os campos dos arquivos entregues
        field = [layerDefinition.GetFieldDefn(i).GetName() for i in range(layerDefinition.GetFieldCount())]
        # test
        # Name of file without extension
        name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(self.vector_path))[0]
        return (name)
```

And it is easier with [Fiona](http://toblerity.org/fiona/manual.html) (another Python wrapper of OGR)

```
import fiona
class checkVectorMCV(object):
    def __init__(self, vector_path):
        self.vector_path = vector_path
    def check_field_name(self):
        self.dataSource = fiona.open(self.vector_path)
        field = self.dataSource.schema['properties'].keys()
        # tests
        name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(self.vector_path))[0]
        return (name)
```

Or [GeoPandas](http://geopandas.org/) (Python 2.7.x or 3.x)

```
import geopandas as gp
class checkVectorMCV(object):
    def __init__(self, vector_path):
       self.vector_path = vector_path #os.path.abspath(vector_path)
    def check_field_name(self):
       self.dataSource = gp.read_file(self.vector_path)
       field = self.dataSource.columns
       # test
       return (name)
```

Answer (score 2):

If the file name passed to ogr.Open() is not a valid ogr format, then a NoneType object will be created instead of a DataSource. This is causing the error message when the GetLayer method is called on the NoneType object.

So some of the files in the directory tree are not valid ogr formats, and as soon as your program reaches one of these the error is encountered. Possibly these could be the .prj .shx .dbf files associated with shapefiles?

A solution to this problem could be to check the validity of your DataSource at the start of the check_field_name method:

```
def check_field_name(self):

    # Construindo a lista de campos do arquivo entregues

    if not self.vector_path:
        return "Invalid ogr format"
```